# Finding if List in Input()

Tags: python

I'm attempting to find out when a list is in someone's input, here's the code:

```
Sad = ['sad','broken','depressed','sadness','grief',]

Input = input("Hi ").strip()

if Sad in Input:
    print("Word Found")
else:
    print("Word Not Found")
```

It works when you have one of the words in the list alone, but when it's a sentence including the word it returns as false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, it's the reverse: `if Input in Sad`: you're trying to find an element, `Input`, in the `Sad` list  ;)

If you want it to work with sentences in `Input`, you'll have to update your logic:

1. Split `Input` into a list of word
2. Loop on each word
3. See if the word is present in `Sad`

```py
Sad = ['sad','broken','depressed','sadness','grief',]


# split(" ") will split the string that is given as an input
# into a list of strings, using " " as a separator.
Input = input("Hi ").strip().split(" ")

for word in in Input:
    if word in Sad:
        print("Word {} Found".format(word)
    else:
        print("Word {} Not Found".format(word)
```

You can make this even easier using [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```py
Sad = {'sad','broken','depressed','sadness','grief'}
Input = set(input("Hi ").strip().split(" "))
matching_words = Input & Sad

if matching_words:
    print("Some words found:", matching_words)
else:
    print("No words found)
```

Comment: This works, but ran into the other issue. It returns false if you add another word onto it. (Responding to Agate unsure of whether the @ went through).

Comment: `if you add another word onto it` -> do you mean in the `Input` ?

Comment: Yes, when I put, "Sad", for the input it clarifies at as true but if I put, "I am sad", it clarifies it as false.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you how to do that :)

Comment: Ignore my last response, I have a literal coconut for a brain and didnt realize it prints not word for every word that isn't in the list.

Comment: I would suggest changing `Sad` to a `set` for more efficient membership checks.

Comment: agreed @Jab, I've updated my answer, thank you

Comment: Don't forget to change it in the original code as well.

Comment: I'd rather keep the original code, to make it consistend with the original question and snippet :)

Comment: @Agate Thank you for the sets one, that was exactly what I needed. Original worked but it was a bit confusing for me. BUT, after testing with a sentence that has none of the set words in it, it gives true.

Comment: Can you share the input? I don't think it's possible e.g: `assert len({'sad','broken','depressed','sadness','grief'} & {"i", "feel", "fine"}) == 0`

Comment: @Agate, think something happened when I attached it to the original project that screwed it up, works jus fine in a new project.  Yep, something was screwing it up, I guess that's it. Thanks for the help!